# Java simple if/else statement

Tags: java

I am making a blackjack game and for some reason can't get the else statement to work. Can you correct this and explain correctly please?

```
 {
    if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("next card"))
        b = ran.nextInt(1 + 9) + 1;
        y = x + c + b;
        System.out.println("You received " + b + " And together your cards equal " + y + " .");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You decided to stay.");
    }
```

OR
http://prntscr.com/20rq6s

Comment: Please format your code before posting it here to make it easier for those helping you.

Comment: hey and welcome to stackoverflow. Here at stackoverflow we really LOVE codeformatting :) formating makes live so much easier

Comment: The last edit add the missing brackets '{' and '}'. This make the question a bit puzzling ;)

Answer (score 7):

Use brackets correctly, you have your brackets outside of the "if" block:

```
if (/*condition*/) {
    // Do code
} else {
    // Do other code
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if you don't use brackets, the if statement terminates at the first semi-colon (;).  Id' suggest reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Comment: While true, even for single-statement if conditions I personally put brackets, it makes the code a lot cleaner imho.

Comment: Oh, absolutely, just trying to show the OP why his program is doing what it is.  Always always always use brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(user.equalsIgnoreCase("next card")) { 
    b = ran.nextInt(1 + 9)+1; 
    y = x + c + b; 
    System.out.println("You received " +b+ " And together your cards equal " +y+ " ."); 
} else { 
    System.out.println("You decided to stay."); 
}
```

Comment: While this is correct, spoon-feeding the answer to someone who doesn't grasp a concept this basic, will hurt them in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have the correct structure to your `IF` statement. Have a look at the following article... it will explain the required structure.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Hopefully it will clear up any confusion you may have.

Hope this helps.